# KQL: How to put unique values from a column as names of columns

Tags: kql

I want to gather unique entries from one column and pass them as column names to display their count values.

```
let sales = datatable (store: string, category: string, product: string)
[
    "StoreA", "Food", "Steak",
    "StoreB", "Drink", "Cola",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Fries",
    "StoreA", "Sweets", "Cake",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Hotdog",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Salad",
    "StoreA", "Sweets", "Chocolate",
    "StoreC", "Food", "Steak"
];
sales
| summarize Food=count(category=="Food"),Drink=count(category=="Drink"),Sweets=count(category=="Sweets") by store
```

It can be done manually, but I want to make this query universal, so it doesn't need to be changed when new categories are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting rows to columns is called "pivoting".

See KQL [pivot plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin)

```
let sales = datatable (store: string, category: string, product: string)
[
    "StoreA", "Food", "Steak",
    "StoreB", "Drink", "Cola",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Fries",
    "StoreA", "Sweets", "Cake",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Hotdog",
    "StoreB", "Food", "Salad",
    "StoreA", "Sweets", "Chocolate",
    "StoreC", "Food", "Steak"
];
sales
| evaluate pivot(category, count(), store)
```

| store | Drink | Food | Sweets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StoreA | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| StoreB | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| StoreC | 0 | 1 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA31QywqDMBC8B/IPiycFv6Clh9ZSevdYetiaxYrBlWS1FPrxjQHpE7OHLDOZ2c1YEvBoycMGDEqoiyVIvbCjFXhxTVfnUKFQze7%20QnrHZqhkBjKtTlpBOEk5SbdJDsmB2Ux3KYRtkr/zuwnfB2U7NQVb/MPP%20oNryH/y0b%208EYmPBtjSgsGRxXC98KBEi2Z5wpWrsKV8jSl%20/6nVea1VzFSrB9CIdgg66JuRJZ2TDJny0Ema5RCzzp7sKnuniQEAAA==)